# server-side javascript check fails automated form based login

Tags: javascript, android, forms, authentication

Developing my first Android app I think I've hit a bit of a road block.

My app is meant to automatically log in to a website and query the site for some search terms and display the results on the screen. I specifically do not want to use a browser as I like to get rid of most of the site's overhead (pictures, ads, etc..).

Using a form-based login to a website using HttpURLConnection I am stuck at the point where the server acknowledges my login, but then checks for my browser's javascript and cookie capabilities and stops the login. The server comes back with a neatly crafted page saying something like 'Hey, thanks for the login but you need to enable javascript and cookies, goodbye', so it's not a HTTP or connection error or so.

Relevant code:

```
        InputStream myInputStream =null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // prepare login fields
        sb.append("username=");    
        sb.append(username);           
        sb.append("&password=");   
        sb.append(password);

        myurl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myurl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        // add the POST form fields to the request
        wr.write(sb.toString());
        wr.flush();
        myInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        wr.close();
```

I am able to trigger the same server behaviour with Lynx (console based browser for Linux that also doesn't have javascript) which gives me the same page saying that I cannot use the site unless I have javascript enabled in my browser.

Ideally I would just like to fool the server and let it know that I am javascript capable, but I don't know if this is possible with my current method.

If that doesn't work, what are my alternatives? Do I have to use something like WebViewClient? As said I don't need a browser gui, just a way to extract data from the html and do something with it in my app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link to the website so we can see how it's checking for JS support

Comment: The site uses a time-based login form. After the main url is meant to go a unix epoch (seconds since 1970 I believe) counter. Try: http://www.qrz.com/li/1330595715

Answer (score 0):

The web server may be checking your `User-agent` header and comparing against a whitelist of supported browsers.  Try doing this before sending the request:

```
conn.setRequestProperty(
    "User-agent", 
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11");
```

Comment: Really good suggestion but the site must be using something else other than checking for the User-agent as I tried the above user agent as well as FireFox for WinXP/32bit user agent string and both resulted in the same 'sorry but no go without javascript' info page.